# Botão favoritar estilo facebook

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Como criar um botão favoritar estilo o like do facebook que após clicar fica marcado e envia a request ao banco de dados em plano de fundo, algo assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O Primeiro botão é o do estado normal e o segundo é após ser clicado e inserido no banco de dados que a publicação foi curtida, tudo isso em background sem refresh, estou fazendo isso numa pequena aplicação MVC, então como seria a comunicação por background?

```
<a href="post/like/" class="btn_nornal">Favoritar</a>
```

Comment: Sobre front, consigo trabalhar no back end, só queria saber como seria essa comunicação, não sei nada de front rs

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar requisição AJAX para fazer isso.

Eu sugiro que você crie 3 classes para o botão.

- Uma classe para o estado normal (vamos dizer, default)
- Uma classe de loading, enquanto a operação ainda está rodando em background (vamos dizer, esperando)
- Uma classe de concluído (vamos dizer, concluido)

O script seria algo como:

```
$("#favorite").on("click", function(){
   $("#favorite").addClass("esperando");
   $.post($("#favorite").attr("href"), {
      //aqui algum dado para ser enviado para o servidor
      id: "3213",
      user: "user1",
      data: new Date()
}).done(function(data){
   //Se retorno for ok, setar a classe do botao para concluido
   $("#favorite").addClass("concluido").
   $("#favorite").removeClass("default");
   $("#favorite").removeClass("esperando");
}).fail(function(data){
   //Se algo deu errado, setar botao para default novamente
   $("#favorite").removeClass("esperando");
   $("#favorite").removeClass("concluido");
   $("#favorite").addClass("default");
});
}
```

Para melhorar o gerenciamento, é interessante salvar o valor de `$("#favorite")` em alguma variável, dessa forma, não precisa utilizar o selector do JQuery a todo momento.

Answer (score 1):

Há "**n**" maneiras de fazer isso, mas uma forma simples de chegar isso, usando jQuery é assim:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn_nornal">Favoritar</a>
```

No exemplo abaixo ele faz uma requisição "autoload" ajax, ao carregar a página que verifica o status:

```
  $(function(){
      var user_id = '123'; 
      //checa o status ao carregar a página...
       actionFavorite('checar', user_id);
      //favorita
       $('.btn_normal').on('click', function(){
          actionFavorite('favoritar', user_id);
       });
    });

    function actionFavorite(action, user_id) {
    $.post('check-or-add-status-favorite.php',{action:action, id:user_id},function(e){
           var statusClass = jQuery.parseJSON(e);
              if (statusClass.status == 'active') {
                 $('.btn_normal').addClass(statusClass.status);
                 $('.btn_normal').text(statusClass.txt)
              } else {
                 $('.btn_normal').removeClass('active');
                 $('.btn_normal').text(statusClass.txt)
              }
       });
    }
```

e no PHP:

```
<?php
$action = $_POST['action'];
$user_id = $_POST['id'];
$status = 'active';
$txt = 'Favoritos';

if ($action == 'checar') {
   $consulta = $pdo->query("SELECT status_favorito
                            from usuarios
                            WHERE id_usuario=:id_usuario;");
   $consulta->bindParam(':id_usuario',(int) $user_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
   $consulta->execute();
   $row = $consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    //se já for gravado, será: 'active', caso constrário, ele emprimirá ''; 
   if ($row['status_favorito'] == 'active') {
       $txt = 'Favoritos';
   } else {
     //reseta se não estiver ativo
     $status = '';
     $txt = 'Favoritar';
   }
   echo json_encode(array(
                     'status' =>  $status,
                     'txt' =>  $txt
                         ));
} else {
 //faz update se ação: 'favoritar'
 $consulta = $pdo->query("UPDATE usuarios SET
                           status_favorito=:status
                          WHERE id_usuario=:id_usuario;");
 $consulta->bindParam(':status',$status, PDO::PARAM_STR);
 $consulta->bindParam(':id_usuario',(int) $user_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
 $consulta->execute();
 echo json_encode(array('status' => $status, 'txt'=> $txt ));
}
```

Comment: Só lembrando que isso aqui (misturar PHP no JS):
  var user_id = '<?php echo $user_id?>';
 é uma gambiarra.

Comment: cara, isso é um exemplo simples, dá pra passar também no json,

Comment: Concordo que existam "n" maneiras de fazer o que ele perguntou, todavia poderia ter feito o seu código consumir a variável de um hidden ou qualquer outra coisa que seja menos "gambiarra" do que misturar PHP e JS. Essa é apenas a minha sugestão, em momento algum disse que não funcionaria =)

Comment: a parte que carrega a ID, será uma outra implementação, não vejo a necessidade para a demonstração da resposta, neste caso. É irrelevante. Poderia esta representado de várias formas... até em um atributo do tipo data-id do elemento.

Comment: entendo =) (sem problemas, é que a pergunta dele é apenas como enviar o request, por isso achei "irrelevante" adicionar uma linguagem diferente de JS na resposta).

Comment: Eu tirei para não incomodar. Ok

Comment: Na verdade, a verificação com o nome do botão seria só no front end, algo como: se o json gerado pelo php retornar true/1 para positivo, que o post foi adicionado aos favoritos ,o javascript mudaria a classe e o texto do botão, caso contrário seria lançado um request e assim mudar o status do botão, não gostaria de misturar códigos. Obrigado pelos comentários!

Answer (score -1):

Seguindo a linha de raciocínio do Andrew, adicionei algumas das boas práticas.

Criei esse exemplo prático, http://jsfiddle.net/2c6ok23e/4/ e espero ter ajudado.

Abraço